# I am looking for point of interest (POI) icons which would be suitable for use with MapQuest

Tags: icon, resource-recommendations

I'm developing a web application for our company that uses MapQuest and we are trying to plot different items on the map. The default MapQuest icon is a purple circle, we need to use different coloured push pins for different groups of POI's.

Is there any site I might find icons that I may freely use or could someone point me in the direction to create my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [these](http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/category/markers/restaurants-bars/?style=gradient) before.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I'm after, thank you very much CapsicumDreams.